# SQL View: Comparing an initial table with a profiling table to return values not present in initial table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I have 2 tables in my database. The first table contains multiple Routes and patrols. Each route may have multiple patrols on it. For each patrol, a number of tags are submitted. The second table contains just routes and tags, basically the complete tag set for that route.

I need to for each patrol return the values from the second table that were not present (aka list the tags that were not recorded on that route and patrol).

```
**Table:Data Import:**
RouteID
PatrolID
TagID

**Table:Routes**
RouteID
TagID
```

Does this make sense? I have tried NOT IN, LEFT JOINS, and NOT EXISTS, but I cant seem to get my logic correct. My most recent attempt (in full) was as follows:

Oh and I am creating a view. I would like the coloumns below to be included in my output, but you need not use them in your response.

```
 CREATE VIEW TagsNotPresent AS
    SELECT 
    [Data Import].[Company name], 
    [Data Import].[Site name], 
    [Data Import].[Patrol ID], 
    [Data Import].[Route id], 
    [Data Import].[Occurrence date], 
    [Data Import].[Tag name] 
    FROM [Data Import]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Routes 
    ON Routes.[Route id] = [Data Import].[Route id] 
    AND Routes.[Tag name] = [Data Import].[Tag name] 
    WHERE Routes.[Tag name] IS NULL
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCEPT` may help you:

```
SELECT r.RouteId,di.PatrolID,r.TagId
    FROM Routes r
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RouteId, PatrolID from DataImport) as di on di.RouteId = r.RouteId
EXCEPT
SELECT RouteId,PatrolID,TagId
FROM DataImport
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, repetition... Sample output below:

Comment: Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920 
The Kennedy - 0766145665 T.K. Passage 208  25~1239920

Comment: Try to add 'DISTINCT' to first 'SELECT' :
'SELECT **DISTINCT** r.RouteId,di.PatrolID,r.TagId
 FROM Routes r
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RouteId, PatrolID from DataImport) as di on di.RouteId = r.RouteId
EXCEPT
SELECT RouteId,PatrolID,TagId
FROM DataImport'

Comment: How would I now add a coloumn in that output from the [Data Import] table? (Datetime)? Merely tagging along, no relationships with anything...

Comment: As I understand, you want to add to VIEW only rows which do not exist in [Data Import] table. In this case you can add to output only columns with empty or NULL values, i.e.
  
`SELECT DISTINCT r.RouteId, di.PatrolID, r.TagId, '' as AdditionalColumn`

Don't forget add this column to second `SELECT` too.

Comment: The coloumns already exist in the dataimport table, and have values. THe output of your solution (in a view) would give us three coloumns. I would like to alongside these three coloumns include 2 more coloumns that exist in the [Data Import] table, and already contain values. Does that clarify this for you?

Comment: According your task description, you want to get "the values from the second table that were not present" in [Data Import] table. Therefore if you have in [Data Import] some rows it will be excluded from output.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the minus-SQL-order. I selected all possible route and tag-Combinations and subtracted all existing. I hope that is what you wanted.

```
  select distinct patrol_id, routes.*
   from data_import
   join routes
   on data_import.route_id = routes.route_id
 minus
   select patrol_id, routes.* 
   from data_import
   join routes
   on data_import.route_id = routes.route_id and data_import.tag_id = routes.tag_id;
```